# Rhythmbox missing japanese/chinese/korean characters in the song titles

Tags: banshee, rhythmbox, language-support

I've got in the database several japanese/chinese/korean song that are shown with "random" characters (I think I should install a language package... but I don't know which one).

Comment: You should split this up into 3 questions, you'll be more likely to get answers that way.

Comment: I thought It was more clear in this manner, but if I should split the questions, I'll do.. :)

Comment: I'm splitting questions how suggested

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you have correct representation of Japanese, Chinese, and Korean characters in your song database, but these are not being rendered appropriately in the display.  In this case, the most likely cause is missing font support.  To install the preferred fonts for these environments, install the following packages:

- language-support-fonts-ko (Korean)
- language-support-fonts-ja (Japanese)
- language-support-fonts-zh-hans (Simplified Chinese)
- language-support-fonts-zh-hant (Traditional Chinese)

If you happen to be running Ubuntu 8.04, the name of the packages for the Chinese fonts is different (I can't seem to find it just now).  These packages do not appear to be available for oneiric: I believe this functionality is being integrated with the language-support tool, and do not know precisely how it will be represented when 11.10 is released.

Comment: I've installed the language support....... but files still shown with messed character... maybe is a problem within rythmbox or the tag of files itself..

Comment: In that case, the issue isn't about fonts, but that the character isn't represented correctly in the tag.  You will need to convert the strings from the current representation to UTF-8, if sufficient information remains in the original files to do so.  You could try with iconv(1), for example `iconv -f SJIS-WIN textfile` to convert older Japanese files on Windows.  Unfortunately, this is more complicated when dealing with media metadata, as the tag informaiton is not a text file.  You may be able to extract the tags, but the process of extraction may corrupt the strings.  Best of luck.

Comment: Ok, I'll try with iconv :)

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem too.

I usually use EasyTAG to fix my mp3 file info. But some of my korean songs were shown with "random" characters. I try to fix it several times in EasyTAG, but it didn't work (copy paste from google's results).

Finally, I have fixed this. You can directly change it from Rhythmbox.

Right click the song > Properties.

You can edit the field like title, artist, and more. Of Course with compatible encoding. And it works.